# Is it possible to render to an 8-bit texture framebuffer on OpenGL ES 2.0 / iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer

I need to render something to an off-screen buffer and read the pixels back into "CPU memory" by calling `glReadPixels`. My code works great when compiled to normal OpenGL under Windows, but to make it run under OpenGL ES 2.0 in iOS, I had to replace the `GL_ALPHA` (or `GL_LUMINANCE`) texture with an `GL_RGBA` one, meaning

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,  width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

instead of

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA,  width, height, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

I wasn't able to run the code with an 8-bit texture.

But since I don't need the full colors on this rendering, those extra 3 bytes per pixel are wasted. Before I try it again, here my question:

**Has anyone succeeded to off-screen-render to an 8-bit texture and reading the bytes back into CPU memory? Is it possible at all?**

Answer (score 2):

Set the glRenderbufferStorage format to GL_R8_EXT, and the glReadPixels/glTexImage2D formats to GL_RED_EXT.

http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_rg.txt

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW47

Edit: I've tested this and it works, but only on A5 and above (iPad2/3/4/mini, iPhone4S/5, iPod touch 5th gen). Unfortunately it's not available on A4 and older where it's needed most (iPhone4, iPod touch 4th gen, 3GS, iPad1).

Answer (score 0):

To make it run in OpenGL 3.0, you could use GL_R8 for buffer buffers:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_renderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_R8, 640, 480);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                          GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderBuffer);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) ;
if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
  NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
}
```